# Installed Linux on Asus 100TA but webcam is not working

Tags: linux, drivers, webcam, asus-laptop

I have an Asus 100TA laptop which came with Windows 8.1 pre-installed.

I decided to install Linux Mint on the laptop because the Windows was very buggy.

I installed Linux Mint 19.3 on the laptop.
Everything except for the webcam, Wi-Fi and speakers worked fine!
After some tinkering I managed to get the Wi-Fi and the speakers to work. But not the webcam!

The webcam is Aptina MT9M114.
I have tried to install the driver from here: https://github.com/jfwells/linux-asus-t100ta/tree/master/mt9m114-driver, but the webcam is still not working:

1. I run ***make*** command and it was succesfull and I got a *mt9m114.ko* file.
2. I run ***sudo make install*** and the *mt9m114.ko* file was installed in the kernel directory.
3. I run ***sudo modprobe mt9m114*** and the module was succesfully added to the kernel.

After adding the module to the kernel I excepted to have a device file in ***/dev*** called ***video0***, but it has not been created!

When I run ***dmesg*** it shown me this.

```
...
[  400.052999] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[  400.071954] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[  400.077423] mt9m114: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  400.299425] mt9m114 3-0048: chip found @ 0x90 (Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter)
```

Please help me. I don't know what is the problem, and I want to make the camera working!

Thank you.

Comment: "With Windows 8.1 everything worked fine." and "because the Windows was very buggy"... well, which is it?

Comment: I mean that all the hardware worked fine with Windows.

Comment: It might not necessarily be the mt9m114 depending on your exact model. Is it a t100, a t100TA, a T100TAM...? dmesg seems like its finding the USB controller instead.  I never managed to make my T100TA webcam work with Ubuntu either.

Comment: Just want to say that these tablets work perfectly fine on Windows 10...

Comment: I have the Asus 100TA and I am sure in 100% that the camera is MT9M114, because it is responding to I2C commands (look in the last line in the dmesg output).

Comment: I know that Windows 10 works good with  tablets like that, but I want to have Linux as the operating system and the only thing that is not working is the webcam and I want to fix it.